# Find a limit or prove it doesn't exist $\lim_{(x, \space y) \to (0, \space 0)} \frac{xy + \arcsin \sqrt[5]{x^2y^4}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find a limit or prove it doesn't exist
$$\lim_{(x, \space y) \to (0, \space 0)}  \frac{xy + \arcsin \sqrt[5]{x^2y^4}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

---

I've tried substitution $x = r \cdot \cos \phi, \space y = r \cdot \sin \phi$, which gave me $ \frac{r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi + \arcsin\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}}{r} $. So, if I'm not mistaken
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi + \arcsin\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}}{r} = $$  $$= \lim_{r \to 0} r\cos\phi\sin\phi + \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\arcsin\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}}{r} = $$
$$= \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\arcsin\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}}{r} $$
and here I'm stuck. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final limit is equal to $0$, since$$0\leqslant\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}\leqslant r^{\frac65}$$and therefore (since $\arcsin$ is increasing and $\arcsin(0)=0$)$$0\leqslant\frac{\arcsin\left(\sqrt[5]{r^6\cos^2\phi\sin^4\phi}\right)}r\leqslant\frac{\arcsin\left(r^{\frac65}\right)}r=\sqrt[5]r\frac{\arcsin\left(r^{\frac65}\right)}{r^{\frac65}}\to0.$$